# How Can I change header content with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am trying to make a very simple welcome page in my site, and I want to greet users with "good morning ....", Taking names is not a thing, but my javascript part is not working, or I can not call it out, so here is my code:

```
<body style="background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255)">
 

  <h3 style="color: green">
    <%=ServletUtility.getSuccessMessage(request)%>
  </h3>
  <br>
  <h3 class="greeting" id="greeting">
    "greet()"
  </h3>
 <script>
    function greet(){
      var date1=new Date();
      var hour=date1.getHours();
      alert(hour);
      var header = document.getElementById("greeting");
      if(hour>0 && hour <=12){
        header.innerHTML="Good Morning"+" "+ <%=session.getAttribute("user")%>;
      }
      else if (hour >12 && hour <= 18){
        header.innerHTML="Good Afternoon" + " " +<%=session.getAttribute("user")%>;   
      }else if (hour >18 && hour <=22){
        header.innerHTML="Good Evening"+" "+ <%=session.getAttribute("user")%>;
      }else{ 
        header.innerHTML="Good Night"+" "+ <%=session.getAttribute("user")%>;
      }  
  
    
 }
  </script>
</body>
```

can anyone help me?, I am new at javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript functions can only be executed in `<script></script>` tags.

your header:

```html
  <h3 class="greeting" id="greeting">
    "greet()"
  </h3>
```

will thus not execute the greet function, but instead display "greet()".

You can solve this by calling the function inside the script tag, like this:

```js
 <script>
    function greet(){
      var date1=new Date();
      var hour=date1.getHours();
      alert(hour);
      var header = document.getElementById("greeting");
      if(hour>0 && hour <=12){
        header.innerHTML="Good Morning"+" "+ "<%=session.getAttribute("user")%>";
      }
      else if (hour >12 && hour <= 18){
        header.innerHTML="Good Afternoon" + " " +"<%=session.getAttribute("user")%>";   
      }else if (hour >18 && hour <=22){
        header.innerHTML="Good Evening"+" "+ "<%=session.getAttribute("user")%>";
      }else{ 
        header.innerHTML="Good Night"+" "+ "<%=session.getAttribute("user")%>";
      }  

    
   }
  
   //add this line
   greet();
  </script>
```

You can also remove the 'greet()' from your `<h3>` tag.

Notice that i've placed your `"<%=session.getAttribute("user")%>"` between quotes.
`<%=session.getAttribute("user")%>` is server generated. This means it will place its contents (e.g. "John") as raw text. If the quotes wouldn't be there, you'd get:

```js
 header.innerHTML="Good Night"+" "+ john;
```

which would throw a reference error: john is treated as an uninitialized variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, helped me a lot, in your code, greet() is still in bracklet parathesis, so I pulled it outside and it worked perfectly well, thank you :)

Comment: yeah you're right, i noticed just when you accepted. Corrected now. Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

I've never used JSP but I'd imagine that `<%=` is used to echo a string so with that in mind I'd use that to generate a javascript variable outside of the function `Greet` and supply that variable as an argument to the function.
The method by which you have attempted to call your `Greet` function is not correct - the function should either be within the script or as an inline event handler, such as `onclick=Greet()` but that would not be applicable here.

```js
const username='<%=session.getAttribute("user")%>';


const Greet=( user )=>{
  let now=new Date();
  let hour=now.getHours();
  let msg=`Good night ${user}`;
  
  if( hour > 0 && hour < 12 )msg=`Good morning ${user}`;
  else if( hour > 12 && hour < 17 )msg=`Good afternoon ${user}`;
  else if( hour > 17 && hour < 22 )msg=`Good evening ${user}`;

  document.querySelector('h3.greeting').textContent=msg;
};

Greet( username );
```

```html
<h3 class="greeting" id="greeting"></h3>
```